# Redirecting to custom action after save in Rails Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, custom-action, rails-admin

I have been working with Rails Admin, and I want to customize the redirect after the create and update actions for a model.

I created a new plugin and I have it set up in the backend. I can click the tab, and it takes me to the view page. What I'd like to do is rewrite the edit and create actions to redirect to this page after save/update.

I've searched on google, but for some reason, everything I try doesn't work. Any insight would be welcome.

Thank you.

=====

I'm trying to redirect to a crop page afterwards. I'm not sure where I would put that code. Do I put it into the RailsAdminCrop module below? If so, how? The documentation doesn't mention this.

Configuration:

```
require 'rails_admin/config/actions'
require 'rails_admin/config/actions/base'
require "rails_admin_crop/engine"

module RailsAdminCrop
end

module RailsAdmin
  module Config
    module Actions
      class Crop < RailsAdmin::Config::Actions::Base


        register_instance_option :member do
          true
        end

        register_instance_option :link_icon do
          'icon-th-large'
        end

        register_instance_option :controller do
         Proc.new do
           flash.now[:notice] = ": #{@object.title}." 
         end
       end


      end
    end
  end
end
```

or do I put it into the rails_admin.rb initializer by passing a block to the edit action? And if so, what configuration do I put?

```
  module RailsAdmin
    module Config
      module Actions
        class Crop < RailsAdmin::Config::Actions::Base
          RailsAdmin::Config::Actions.register(self)
        end
      end
    end
  end

 config.actions do
    dashboard
    index
    new

    crop

    show
    edit
    delete
  end
```

After rake routes (It's the default routes):

```
Routes for RailsAdmin::Engine:
    dashboard GET         /                                      rails_admin/main#dashboard
        index GET|POST    /:model_name(.:format)                 rails_admin/main#index
          new GET|POST    /:model_name/new(.:format)             rails_admin/main#new
       export GET|POST    /:model_name/export(.:format)          rails_admin/main#export
  bulk_delete POST|DELETE /:model_name/bulk_delete(.:format)     rails_admin/main#bulk_delete
history_index GET         /:model_name/history(.:format)         rails_admin/main#history_index
  bulk_action POST        /:model_name/bulk_action(.:format)     rails_admin/main#bulk_action
         show GET         /:model_name/:id(.:format)             rails_admin/main#show
         edit GET|PUT     /:model_name/:id/edit(.:format)        rails_admin/main#edit
       delete GET|DELETE  /:model_name/:id/delete(.:format)      rails_admin/main#delete
 history_show GET         /:model_name/:id/history(.:format)     rails_admin/main#history_show
  show_in_app GET         /:model_name/:id/show_in_app(.:format) rails_admin/main#show_in_app
```

Comment: What have you tried? Can you give us your code for the controller where you are trying to redirect the create and update actions?
And where do you want them redirect them? Also try to give the rake routes list

Comment: I updated the question to include my code, routes, and further questions.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe you can do this through configuration, you will need to extend the plugin. Also, you can use only one redirect_to or render per action so you will need to assign the action to a variable and then call it at the very end.

```
register_instance_option :controller do
  Proc.new do

    flash.now[:notice] = ": #{@object.title}."

    if request.post? || request.put?
      some_action = "do_something"
    else
      some_action =  @action.template_name
    end

    render :action => some_action
  end
end
```